# My @Startup singleton does not start in JavaEE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton

I got the following Singleton code:

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
@javax.ejb.Startup
public class SingletonWhichIsSupposedToStart {

  @PostConstruct
  public void ready(){
  //there is a breakpoint on the next line
  System.out.println("singleton ready");
  }
}
```

But when I start the application in debug mode (on Glassfish3), nor the 'singleton ready' is printed, nor the breakpoint is triggered. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Seems that the class is deployed, and can be injected, but the lifecycle method @PostConstruct is ignored.

Comment: can you check if it works without debug mode?

Comment: Interesting. What happens if you inject this bean into another bean (and initialize it)? Will the `@PostConstruct` fire? I see that you say it can be injected, but I mean what happens after the injecting bean is actually initialized, say, injecting this `@PostConstruct` bean into a REST controller, and hitting the endpoint?

Comment: Does that version of glassfish support EJB 3.1?